# Encrypt QR codes

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, qr-code

I am developing an Android app and a web administration module. I need to generate QR codes, but encrypted (since these reveal sensitive information in the database).

The QR codes are generated in PHP and are read by the android app. I have been reviewing this documentation of Halite, which I think is very good.

https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/master/doc/Basic.md
 
What is your counterpart in java android to decipher the message? Or what other alternative advise me to do this?

Comment: Halite is build on LibSodium so you will need to find a version of LibSodium and add anything on top of it Halite does. Another option is to use [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it has versions for PHP and Java that will interoperate. I uses AES encryption and supports password derivation and has authentication. RNCryptor is fully [documented](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md), secure, well vetted and under current development. Going with a library that is not supported on both platforms leads to insanity.

Answer (score 0):

Android ships with a trimmed version of BouncyCastle, you can find the API documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) .

If the algorithm you are trying to use is not available, you might need to use [SpongyCastle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) which basically BouncyCastle that has been adapted for Android.

My additional advise is also to read [Key Aggreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol) to share the shared secret / key between your server and application.